# Instance of a Functor

Tags: haskell, functor

I have a following type `newtype Arr2 e1 e2 a = Arr2 { getArr2 :: e1 -> e2 -> a }`.
And I got to write Functor instance for it, yet i don't really understand how
I tried

```
instance Functor (Arr2 e1 e2) where
  fmap g (Arr2 a) = Arr2 (g a)
```

and

```
instance Functor (Arr2 e1 e2) where
  fmap g = g . getArr2
```

which actually results in type

```
(a -> b) -> Arr2 e1 e2 a -> b
```

instead of desired

```
(a -> b) -> Arr2 e1 e2 a -> Arr2 e1 e2 b
```

So please, help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) class has as definition:

```
class Functor f where:
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    (<$) :: a -> f b -> f a
```

The `(<$)` has a default implementation: `(<$) = fmap . const` which works fine.

So that means that if we enter a function (`g :: a -> b`) as first argument, and an `Arr2` that produces an `a`, we have to generate an `Arr2` that calls that `g` on the *outcome* of the arrow if it is applied.

As a result the definition of `fmap` for your `Arr2` is:

```
instance Functor (Arr2 e1 e2) where
  fmap g (Arr2 a) = Arr2 (\x y -> g (a x y))
```

Or more elegantly:

```
instance Functor (Arr2 e1 e2) where
  fmap g (Arr2 a) = Arr2 (\x -> g . (a x))
```

Or a more elegant version - commented by [@Alec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178458/haskell-instance-of-a-functor/43178579?noredirect=1#comment73430289_43178579):

```
instance Functor (Arr2 e1 e2) where
  fmap g (Arr2 a) = Arr2 ((g .) . a)
```

(you can convert expressions to *pointfree* ones using [this tool](http://pointfree.io/))

Comment: If you want to get even more <s>unreadable</s> elegant, you can do `fmap g (Arr2 a) = Arr2 ((g .) . a)`.

Comment: @Alec: yeah. Thanks for that suggestion. Updated.

Comment: When pointfree goes beyond a single argument, I like to use [SECs](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators).  This `(.)` section nonsense has never appealed to me

Comment: How would Applicative instance would look like for the type above?

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) is very good, I would just like to suggest the use of a language extension that can easily create `Functor` instances for newtypes: `DeriveFunctor`.

At the top of your module you can add:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
```

Then you can automatically derive your `Functor` instance:

```
newtype Arr2 e1 e2 a = Arr2 { getArr2 :: e1 -> e2 -> a } deriving Functor
```

Here's is how I would find out the type of `fmap` for this instance in GHCi:

```
λ > :set -XDeriveFunctor
λ > newtype Arr2 e1 e2 a = Arr2 { getArr2 :: e1 -> e2 -> a } deriving Functor
λ > :set -XTypeApplications 
λ > :t fmap @(Arr2 _ _)
fmap @(Arr2 _ _) :: (a -> b) -> Arr2 t t1 a -> Arr2 t t1 b
```